# C Programming Keeps Crashing

Tags: c

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong; I get a clean compile but after inputting the first number, it crashes.

```
    for (day = 1; day < 15; day++)
{
    do
        {
            printf("What is the temperature high for day #%d? ", day++);
            scanf("%d", temperature[day]);

            sum += temperature[day];

                if (temperature[day]<0 || temperature[day]>100)
                {
                    printf("\nOut of range, please enter a value from 0 to 100\n\n");
                }


            if (temperature[day] < 60)
                {
                    cold++;
                }

            else if (temperature[day] >= 60)
                {
                    warm++;
                }

            else if (temperature[day] > 69 || temperature[day] < 80)
                {
                    printf("Wow! It's in the 70's today!");
                    warm++;
                }
```

Any help, even a hint, would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: where is defined the "temperature" array ?

Comment: sorry! I couldn't show that in this, but above this code i have temperature defined

Comment: sidenote `day` : It is incremented in two places.

Comment: You say "I get a clean compile" but what compiler flags are you using?  Are you using GCC and using the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags?  They are crucial for finding bugs like this.

Comment: 3 answers, and none of the explain *why* `&` is (probably) needed...

Comment: You're also adding the temperature to `sum` before checking if it's out-of-range, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown the definition of `temerature`, but based on your usage,

```
scanf("%d", temperature[day]);
```

should almost certainly be

```
scanf("%d", &temperature[day]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to input from the user , you must provide `&` sign in scanf() function like below,

```
scanf("%d", &temperature[day]);
```

You are missing `&` sign in your scanf() function. Add it and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

mismatch between int and int *.

```
scanf("%d", &temperature[day]);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%d", temperature[day]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     for (day = 1; day < 15; day++)
> {
>     do
> ```

Why do you have both `for()` and `do()` (presumably `do-while()`)?

> ```
>         {
>             printf("What is the temperature high for day #%d? ", day++);
> ```

Do not increment `day` here, it is already incremented as part of the `for` loop, otherwise the interpretation of `day` in rest of the body of the loop is wrong!

> ```
>     scanf("%d", temperature[day]);
> ```

It might be `scanf("%d", & temperature[day]);`, because `scanf()` need the address of the variable.